# I am trying to publish my angular library but its not working

Tags: angular, npm-publish

I am trying to publish my angular package but it's not working for me I am getting this error.

[image]

my package.json file [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to set "enableIvy": false in your tsconfig.lib.json file in angularCompilerOptions section.